# Microsoft Private Cloud: how do I enable web managment?

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud

First thing, this is a college project. I know that I broke some rules on having so many roles on one server, but again this is just to prove to my instructor that I can setup MS Private Cloud.

So, I have my private cloud setup, I have Hyper-V, DC, IIS, SQL Server, Windows ADK, and SCVMM all up an running with Private Cloud hosting 2 Ubuntu VMs.

**What I want to know is, if it is possible for users to open a web browser type the name of the server and be able to sign in to start and view their VMs from the web browser?**

I have read a lot of instructions on how to do this, but all of the instructions are using Windows Azure or Self service portal. Windows Azure is not an option since you have to pay for it, and self service portal no longer come with SCVMM.

Answer (score 1):

Two options. One is the AppController component of System Center 2012. The other is the Azure Pack (WAP), which was released in conjunction with System Center 2012 R2. The latter is more complex, and offers far more in terms of customizations, workflows and automation.

(Just to clarify: The Azure Pack has nothing to do with the paid version of Windows Azure, they simply borrowed some of the codebase from Windows Azure and made it available in a private cloud scenario)

[Kristian Nese (MVP)](http://kristiannese.blogspot.no/) has a blog with tons of good info on the subject

Comment: Alright, I will look into both and see which would be best for I what I need. On all of the instructions I looked at required a Windows Azure account or sign up for a trial. Thanks for your help.